# How to distribute a periodic total value to monthly rows - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to distribute the periodic total amounts to months which are represented on rows. Desired values are shown in column named MONTHLY_COLLECTION_DESIRED.

When a policy has a yearly payment frequency 12 (monthly) then there is nothing to revise. However, payment frequency can change in time and when it is different than 12 (monthly), I need to distribute the PERIODIC_COLLECTION amount to months (rows).

Note: It is possible that PERIODIC_COLLECTION amount can be less than PERIODIC_PREMIUM; when this is the case, remaining amount must be shown in the last row. For instance, when 3 months of PERIODIC_PREMIUM total value is 360 but PERIODIC_COLLECTION is 300, then out of related 3 rows, the value of first two must be 120 and the last one must be 60 which is 300-(120+120).

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Code for data:

```
DROP TABLE MYTABLE;
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (POLICY_ID NUMBER(11), START_OF_MONTH DATE, PLANNED_PAYMENT_DATE DATE, PERIODIC_PREMIUM NUMBER(5), YEARLY_PAYMENT_FREQ NUMBER(2), MONTHLY_PREMIUM NUMBER(5), PERIODIC_COLLECTION NUMBER(5),MONTHLY_COLLECTION_DESIRED NUMBER(5));
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2014-08-01', DATE '2014-08-01',120,12,120, 120, 120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2014-09-01', DATE '2014-09-01',120,12,120, 120, 120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2014-10-01', DATE '2014-10-01',120,12,120, 120, 120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2014-11-01', DATE '2014-11-01',360,4,120, 360, 120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2014-12-01', DATE '2014-11-01',0,4,120, 0, 120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-01-01', DATE '2014-11-01',0,4,120, 0, 120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-02-01', DATE '2015-02-01',360,4,120, 300, 120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-03-01', DATE '2015-02-01',0,4,120, 0, 120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-04-01', DATE '2015-02-01',0,4,120, 0, 60);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-05-01', DATE '2015-05-01',720,2,120, 600, 120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-06-01', DATE '2015-05-01',0,2,120, 0, 120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-07-01', DATE '2015-05-01',0,2,120, 0, 120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-08-01', DATE '2015-05-01',0,2,120, 0, 120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-09-01', DATE '2015-05-01',0,2,120, 0, 120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-10-01', DATE '2015-05-01',0,2,120, 0, 0);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-11-01', DATE '2015-11-01',250,12,250, 250,250);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-12-01', DATE '2015-12-01',250,12,250, 250,250);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2017-01-01', DATE '2017-01-01',60,3,15,60, 15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2017-02-01', DATE '2017-01-01',0,3,15,0, 15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2017-03-01', DATE '2017-01-01',0,3,15,0, 15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2017-04-01', DATE '2017-01-01',0,3,15,0,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2017-05-01', DATE '2017-05-01',60,3,15,40, 15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2017-06-01', DATE '2017-05-01',0,3,15,0, 15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2017-07-01', DATE '2017-05-01',0,3,15,0, 10);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2017-08-01', DATE '2017-05-01',0,3,15,0,0);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2017-09-01', DATE '2017-09-01',15,12,15,15, 15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2017-10-01', DATE '2017-10-01',15,12,15,15, 15);

SELECT * FROM MYTABLE;
```